# Unable to set select selected value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Here is my html code

```
<select id="ddlCountry" placeholder="optional" class="select" title="Select Country">
 <option value="0">Select Country</option>
</select>
```

Here is the jquery code.....

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('select.select').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    if ($('option:selected', this).val() != '') {
      title = $('option:selected', this).text();
      $(this)
        .css({
          'z-index': 10,
          'opacity': 0,
          '-khtml-appearance': 'none'
        })
        .after('<span class="select">' + title + '</span>')
        .change(function () {
          val = $('option:selected', this).text();
          $(this).next().text(val);
        })
    }
  });


  var country = [{
    "CountryID": 1,
    "CountryName": "Afghanistan"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 2,
    "CountryName": "Albania"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 3,
    "CountryName": "Algeria"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 4,
    "CountryName": "American Samoa"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 5,
    "CountryName": "Andorra"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 6,
    "CountryName": "Angola"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 7,
    "CountryName": "Anguilla"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 8,
    "CountryName": "Antarctica"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 9,
    "CountryName": "Antigua and Barbuda"
  }, {
    "CountryID": 10,
    "CountryName": "Argentina"
  }];

  $.each(country, function (index, item) {
    $('#ddlCountry').append($('<option></option>').val(item.CountryID).html(item.CountryName));
  });

  $('#ddlCountry').val(2);
});
```

i have set the drop down value as 2 in ready but the default value is always the `Select Country`

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjSVQ/1/)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: just posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not firing onchange event when programmatically changing selected value of the select. Trigger it manually:

```
$('#ddlCountry').val(2).change();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SjSVQ/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#ddlCountry")[0].selectedIndex = 2;
```

instead of

```
$('#ddlCountry').val(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `.each` function below that line where you are setting the value to `2` this way:

```
 $('#ddlCountry').val(2); //<---below this one

  $('select.select').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    if ($('option:selected', this).val() != '') {
      title = $('option:selected', this).text();
      $(this)
        .css({
          'z-index': 10,
          'opacity': 0,
          '-khtml-appearance': 'none'
        })
        .after('<span class="select">' + title + '</span>')
        .change(function () {
          val = $('option:selected', this).text();
          $(this).next().text(val);
        })
    }
  });
```

[checkout here in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjSVQ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value does not trigger the `change` event.

You can add :

```
$('#ddlCountry').val(2).trigger('change');
```